# Multiple AJAX requests only first one works other fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple inputs and for each of them I have a separate AJAX request.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_1").change(function() {
      var rating1 = $(this).val();
      //                            alert(rating1);
      $.ajax({
        url: "a.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          param_name: rating1
        },
        success: function(response) {
          //                                    alert(response);
          $("#message").html(response);
          // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
      });
    });
  }); < /script>
```

the input code is

```html
<p style="text-align: center;font-size: 15pt;">
  <input type="number" name="your_awesome_parameter" id="id_1" class="rating" data-clearable="remove" data-icon-lib="fa" data-active-icon="fa-heart" data-inactive-icon="fa-heart-o" data-clearable-icon="fa-trash-o" />
</p>
```

I have multiple inputs in seperate divs with unique IDs and those ids are also unique in the AJAX code. When I run it only the first one works but the second one does not.

Code for second input

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_2").change(function() {
      var rating1 = $(this).val();
      //                            alert(rating1);
      $.ajax({
        url: "a.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          param_name: rating1
        },
        success: function(response) {
          //                                    alert(response);
          $("#message").html(response);
          // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;font-size: 15pt;">
  <input type="number" name="your_awesome_parameter" id="id_2" class="rating" data-clearable="remove" data-icon-lib="fa" data-active-icon="fa-heart" data-inactive-icon="fa-heart-o" data-clearable-icon="fa-trash-o" />
</p>
```

Comment: So where's the code for the second one, the one that doesn't work? Did you open the console (F12) and check for errors?

Comment: Problem explanation could definitely use some clarification

Comment: Are you using same id for other input as well ?

Comment: Hi, I have added the code for second one.I have input code and Ajax code in one div then the second one in second div and so on. I have opened the console and it shows no errors. I am using different IDs for each input

Comment: @charlietfl I have multiple inputs on the page and for each input an Ajax request. When the value of the input is changed the Ajax fires up and sends the new value to a page where it is processed. I have added separate ids for each input but its not working only the first one works and if say i add an alert box in the second code it shows in the first one

Comment: should only need one change handler and use a class selector. No need to repeat all this same code over and over

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the suggestion I think I figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion by @charlietfl I made some changes to the code such as now it looks at the class and thus I only have to use the code once and it also get the id of the field as well as input so that I can know which input it came from

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rating").change(function() {
      var rating1 = $(this).val();
      var inputId = $(this).attr("id");
      alert(inputId);
      $.ajax({
        url: "a.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          param_name: rating1,
          id: inputId
        },
        success: function(response) {
          //                                    alert(response);
          $("#message").html(response);
          // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
      });
    });
  }); < /script>
```